# Where are the categories of non-steam games stored locally?

Tags: steam

So I already read this question where they answer a similar question:

[Where are the categories in my Steam library saved? Can I recover them if Steam forgets them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131779/where-are-the-categories-in-my-steam-library-saved-can-i-recover-them-if-steam)

I took a look at that file and it certainly saves the categories for each of my steam games, but I couldn't find any of my non-steam games on that file. I would like to know where are they saved so I can backup them or play with the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The categories for non-Steam games are saved in the same file as their shortcuts:

```
Steam\userdata\:uid\config\shortcuts.vdf
```

[image: cat -v shortcuts.vdf: tags 0 favorite 1 Sillon]